# NextJS - Authentication via external API

Tags: authentication, axios, next.js

[Visual Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x4oB.png)

So basically I have an Express REST API that handles login and everything, I need to create a new service in NextJS that will handle some features, BUT, I wish to use the capability of NextJS of making a request to its own API and only then send the request further to my Express API, further adding an extra layer of security.

My current setup is that I am making an axios POST request from my proxy api to my express api, I receive all my account details and everything, I received my session cookie, but how do I manage to set it? So far I tried sending it to the front separately and set it there, but that does not seem to work.

To be mentioned:
I do have "withCredentials: true" for axios in order to persist the session and make further requests using the cookies token.